# Can I run different componentDidMount() twice?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to convert html API to ReactJS.

Original HTML API:

```
<script src="//dapi.kakao.com/v2/maps/sdk.js?appkey=3199e8f198aff9d5aff73000faae6608"></script>
<script>
    var mapContainer = document.getElementById('map'), 
        mapOption = {
            center: new kakao.maps.LatLng(37.56388, 126.98920),
            level: 6, 
            mapTypeId : kakao.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
        }; 

    var map = new kakao.maps.Map(mapContainer, mapOption); 

</script>
```

My attempt to convert it to React:

```
class App extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.async = true;
        script.src = "https://dapi.kakao.com/v2/maps/sdk.js?appkey=3199e8f198aff9d5aff73000faae6608";
        document.head.appendChild(script);

        script.onload = () => {
            kakao.maps.load(() => {
                let el = document.getElementById('map');
                let map = new kakao.maps.Map(el, {
                    center: new kakao.maps.Coords(523951.25, 1085073.75)
                });
            });
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App" id="map"></div>
        );
    }
}
```

I realized the converted code doesn't show the map.(The original code is running well) I tried combining two scripts in the original code to one, and it didn't show map too. So I think the error is because the two scripts are combined in componentDidMount().

Is there a way to run scripts one by one in React? (Or a way to run HTML in React?)

Thank you.

Comment: Please post any errors you see on the console.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it the React way instead of only copying and pasting the vanilla code, this is how I would do it

Load the Script (I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/scriptjs)

```
const [scriptLoaded, setScriptLoaded] = useState(false);
const url = "https://dapi.kakao.com/v2/maps/sdk.js?appkey=3199e8f198aff9d5aff73000faae6608";

useEffect(() => {
  scriptjs(url, () => setScriptLoaded(true));
}, []);
```

Once loaded get the map from the window

```
useEffect(() => {
  const kakao = window.kakao;
  kakao && kakao.maps.load(() => {
    // your code here
  });
}, [scriptLoaded]);
```